fontawesome brands.scss not able to import _functions.scss
I am trying to add the fontawesome to my Laravel 10 web app. I am getting this error and not sure how to resolve it:

I am not sure why it can't find the functions module because the _function.scss does exist:

Below are steps that I used to add fontawesome:
1) Install sass-embedded => npm add -D sass-embedded
2) Install fontawesome => npm install -D @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
3) Add this alias to vite.config.js => 
'~fontawesome': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free')
4) Add the following to resources/scss/app.scss
   $fa-font-path:'~fontawesome/webfonts';
   @import '~fontawesome/scss/fontawesome';
   @import '~fontawesome/scss/brands';
   @import '~fontawesome/scss/regular';
   @import '~fontawesome/scss/solid';


Thank you for your help

For information, @import has been deprecated for years now..Use @use instead. That @import is still in fontawesome documentation is beyond understanding. Also don't use aliases. Use the relative path. Aliases make your code unusable outside of vite context.

@Eric MORAND Thank you. I replaced the alias "~fontawesome" with relative path "../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free" and that fixed the problem.
